# What is the probability of finding an electron in a hydrogen atom in an infinitesimal space $dV$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability

I have been asked to find the most probable position of electron in infinitesimal space $dV$ orbiting a Hydrogen atom.  I know that probability $P$ of finding the electron in a volume $dV$ is given by
$$
P = |\psi(\vec r,t)|^2 dV
$$
where $\psi(\vec r,t) = A e^{-r/a_0}e^{-iE_1t/\bar{h}}$.

The time dependence is irrelevant and this gives me
\begin{align}
P &= |A|^2e^{-2r/a_0}dV \\
  &= |A|^2e^{-2r/a_0}d^3r \\
  &= |A|^2e^{-2r/a_0}[r^2 \sin(\theta)dr\, d\theta\, d\phi]
\end{align}
My question is what do I do next?  When I differentiate it by $dr$ it will give me $a_0$, but that represents the spherical shell where the probability is highest. Not infinitesimal space with the highest probability.

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're done already when you get to
$$
P = |A|^2e^{-2r/a_0}dV.
$$
Trying to break down $dV$ into its constituent differentials in spherical coordinates will only serve to confuse you.

On the other hand, if you want to give a correct probability, it is essential that you normalize correctly, i.e., that you get an explicit value of $|A|^2$ so that the total probability over all of space is unity.

Comment: Ok thank you. As you sad I was a bit confused by it. Finding normalisation constant is not a problem that is a next part of the exercise I have no problem doing. The question follows with: "If you were able to measure the position only once where would you be measuring?" how do I answer? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @majyno This is not a homework-help site.